# How to color separate white to be the last to print in CMYK printer

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, print-design

Shown below is my white target and exact image to color separate. I use only 4 spots of color, including white, for my plate colors.

[image]

Comment: You can't print white with a CMYK printer. If your printer does not have a white ink cartridge, then you can't print white ink with it.

Comment: We need to clarify here: the title says CMYK, but the body text says 4-color spot plates (not CMYK). Looking at the art, I presume the OP is talking about creating plates from 4 non-process spot colors. This may really be a question about overprinting?

Comment: How is that center area currently filled? are the shapes a % of white or is there a blending mode applied? Or are they a % of the underlying solid color? There are ways to get white on its own plate, but it is necessary to understand the fill structure before making suggestions.

Comment: As Westside said. White will be the last color to be printed... Never, actually n_n

Comment: White **can** be printed and actually is in many production workflows. While it's true general CMYK printing doesn't print white... all Illustrator spot files are CMYK files... and there **are** printing processes where white is printed (silk screen, flexo).

Comment: Dodie, why is white printing last? Why does that matter specifically? when you make the plates the printer is just going to arrange them in the order they want right?

Comment: Also, are you sure that's the exact place you want to be solid white? Not a screen of white? Are you trying to make a screen of white to lighten those colors? Is the shape of all those fruit together supposed to solid white? Please update your question with more specifics of what you actually want to do.

Comment: Dodie, you've made a mistake somewhere. How can it be CMYK + White. That's 5 colors not 4. Is it CMYK or not? Is the yellow and red some pantone color or something? Does your printer only do CMYK?

Comment: Is the white an actual color or is it printed on white substrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not **need** white here at all.

Seems to me simple tints of spot colors can achieve the desired results:

[image]

The *only* reason white would be necessary is if the substrate was *not* white. In that case, you'd print white *first* and then overprint the other colors on top of white to ensure color accuracy. Colors on a non-white substrate *will* darken. You would print a white shape which encompasses *everything*, then overprint the same tints on top of the white.

[image]

I suppose if you are running opaque inks (and white is pretty much always an opaque ink) you may overprint white.

[image]

As for the order of the plates, that's for the pressman to plan and work out. It's his/her job. Designers shouldn't be concerned with the order in which plates are run, only that the artwork separates properly.

Comment: I have already debug it. And I  use this technique now because i will prepare for transparent label. Opaque white first to print. then let the multiplied colors have its color mixing. But then way back when I was looking for answer this method was in my mind. Thanks a lot for your effort. Very keen answer TYVM.

Comment: Sorry I was late to the party @DodieEslava :)

Answer (score 2):

It's actually already in the comments, but in CMYK printing the only white is the plain paper. If you have a porous paper, thin white lines and dots easily vanish due the spreading of the inks.

High gloss photo paper and high quality inks can allow smaller white details than the lower quality ones.

Do some tests. Find the minimum printable white stroke widths and dot diameters for future prints. Have four rectangles. One 100% C, one 100% M, one 100& Y and one 100% black. Have different white lines and dots over them.

Comment: It's plate printing. Not inkjet printing.

Comment: White does print. All the time. Especially when printing labels for larger companies with complicated art. Art that prints over foil, etc... It's very common. Usually it's the first color to be used not the last.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question so far you want to make part of your artwork have a separate color.

I'm still waiting for you to update your question with more specifics.

This is how you separate a color.

1. You would have to first create the white spot color in your swatches
2. Change the object you want to be that spot color.
3. Check your color separations with whatever proprietary tools you have to do so.